# Single Page Wordpress Template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-3.5

I have to convert the following HTML website into a Theme for Wordpress. I am trying to figure out how to structure the theme in terms of pages/posts/custom modules and themes.

I have 5 sections in my page

1. Home (Slider and content)
2. Know (tabs with content)
3. View (Projects with filterable effect)
4. Read (blog and articles)
5. Talk (contact Form)

I want to allow the customer to be able to edit most of the content on the page.

Please guide me into getting started.

Link: http://play.mink7.com/sophiance/

****Edit****

I created a page called `'home'` and in `settings>reading>` selected that as the static content for the site.

Next i created a template called `template-home.php` and selected the `home` to use this template.

Comment: As it stands, this is *extremely* broad. What is your question about exactly?

Comment: @Pekka웃 have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your index.php file put the 5 sections.

in each section - create a new query to pull a page.

for example with a custom post type

```
  <section id="home">
    //Slider Content
<?php query_posts('pagename=home'); if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>//Loop Content
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</section>

<section id="know">
<?php query_posts('pagename=know'); if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>//Loop Content
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</section>
```

etc.

Then create each page with that name and it will pull the data

I created a site like that [here](http://prospectcommons.com/)

Comment: each section has to be defined as a page? and has a template of its own defined as well? do i need to use custom fields ?

Comment: I did it by making a query for each page. so you can write `<?php query_posts('pagename=home'); if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>//Loop Contnet <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>` and each page that gets created by that name will get pulled.

Comment: thanks i will try it out. and get back to you if i have any questions

Comment: can i create custom fields for each section so that i can allow the user to edit the content? can u guide me on how i can do that?

Comment: The whole page is sort of a custom field - so anything in a page will be shown.
additionally just add custom meta boxes to the page and display it accordingly

Comment: any link on how to add custom fields and meta boxes to get started.

Comment: [wptuts](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should structure your Wordpress website:

```
Home (Slider and content) - create a page called Home and a custom page template called home

Know (tabs with content) - use a shortcode plugin to have tabbed content, default page template

View (Projects with filterable effect) - use a plugin that displays content in a masonry layout, default page template

Read (blog and articles) - create posts (under posts) and display them using the post archive.

Talk (contact Form) - use default page template and a plugin like Gravity Themes for the contact form
```

For similar ideas on how to structure your Wordpress website go to http://www.mybuzzmedia.net